# Jquery. Why this works?

Tags: jquery

Can you explain why this http://www.sebastiansulinski.co.uk/demos/jquery_show_hide/ works? 
There is all classes the same, but when you click open, opens only one text. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It only opens one text container because the click event is bound to each individual element matching `div.trigger`.  When you click on one of the matching elements, you are only clicking on one matching element, not all 3 in the example.  Usage of `$(this)` inside the click callback function *only references the clicked element*.

The code can also be cleaned up a little bit by simply chaining calls together:

```
$('div.trigger').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('close').next().slideDown(100);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('close').addClass('open').next().slideUp(100);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

When you click a div with class trigger, it will open up the element next to the trigger using `next()`. The class names don't matter as it operates on `$(this)`, which is the clicked element.

After it has opened the following div, it assigns itself a class 'open' so that it can act differently when the user clicks on it the next time.

The code for that page goes like this:

```
$('div.trigger').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        $(this).addClass('close');
        $(this).next().slideDown(100);
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('close');
        $(this).addClass('open');
        $(this).next().slideUp(100);
        return false;
    }            
});
```

Which, translated to english, goes like this:

```
/*
When .trigger is clicked:
    If it has a class named 'open':
        Remove that class,
        and add a class named 'close'.
        Slide down the element next to this element in 100 milliseconds.
        Prevent other actions from taking place.
    If it hasn't got a class named 'open':
        Remove class 'close',
        and add class 'open'.
        Slide up the element next to this element in 100 milliseconds.
        Prevent other actions from taking place.
```

Answer (score 2):

Some inline commentary might explain this clearly:

```
#If we have divs with the class 'trigger'
if($('div.trigger').length > 0) {
  # Attach logic to the click event of each
  $('div.trigger').click(function() {
    # If this has the class 'open' already
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
      # Remove the class 'open'
      $(this).removeClass('open');
      # Add the class 'close'
      $(this).addClass('close');
      # And slide down the next div
      $(this).next().slideDown(100);
      # Return False
      return false;
    } else {
      # If this didn't have 'open', remove 'close'
      $(this).removeClass('close');
      # Add the class 'open'
      $(this).addClass('open');
      # And slide up the next div
      $(this).next().slideUp(100);
      # Return false
      return false;
    }           
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('div.trigger').click(function()...this...` Means that when you click on a `trigger` class element, the function is applied to only `this`, being the element you clicked on. When you click on it, it gets a new class, `open`, which gives it new properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are operating with $(this) which translates to the button you click.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(document).ready()` function in the source code attaches a new `click` function to **every** `$('div.trigger')` element:

```
$('div.trigger').click(function() {
    // ...
});
```

In the function the **individual** (*current*) div is denoted by `$(this)`.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
    // ...
}
```

In a nutshell, each div has the same function assigned and the function code is written in the perspective of the current (clicked) div.